# ruby regex extract word between single quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a regex to match:

```
ciao: c'iao 'ciao'
```

with:

```
ciao #every word excluding non-word character
c'iao #including apostrophes
ciao #excluding the quotes ''
```

So far I've been able to match the first 2 requirements with:

```
/[\w']+/
```

but I'm struggling with extracting word between single quotes (w/o including the quotes). Note that I won't have a case where a word with apostrophe is included between quotes (like 'c'iao')

I've seen many similar Q&A but couldn't find any suiting my needs; Extra points for an answer that includes a brief explanation :)

Comment: Maybe [`/\w+(?:'\w+)*/`](http://rubular.com/r/Y0SLnzMRrb)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
/\w+(?:'\w+)*/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/Y0SLnzMRrb)

The expression matches:

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:'\w+)*` - zero or more sequences (as `(?:...)*` is a non-capturing group that groups a sequence of subpatterns quantified with `*` quantifier matching 0 or more occurrences) of:

  - `'` - apostrophe
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

See a [short Ruby demo here](http://ideone.com/uw7XHW):

```
"ciao: c'iao 'ciao'".scan(/\w+(?:'\w+)*/)
# => [ciao, c'iao, ciao]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that words can begin or end with an apostrophe, or contain multiple apostrophes, I suggest first splitting on whitespace then removing pairs of single quotes that enclose words.

```
str = "'Twas because Bo didn't like Bess' or y'all's 'attitude'"

str.split.map { |s| s =~ /\A'.+'\z/ ? s[1..-2] : s }
  #=> ["'Twas", "because", "Bo", "didn't", "like", "Bess'", "or", "y'all's", "attitude"]
```

The first step produces

```
arr = str.split
  #=> ["'Twas", "because", "Bo", "didn't", "like", "Bess'", "or", "y'all's", "'attitude'"]
```

The regex matches elements of `arr` that begin and end with a single quote.